# CSOM Caml Query to return list folder sub items

Tags: sharepoint-2013, caml, csom, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm trying to return only list items for a given list folder. However each time i execute the following I get all items in the list.  What's the easiest way to only get list items for a particular folder of a SharePoint list?

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery
{
    ViewXml = "<View Scope=\'Recursive\' />",
    FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Design Items"
};

ListItemCollection listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
```

I was sure if I needed the list name in the FolderServerRelativeUrl property so I've tried the following

```
FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/[ListName]/Design Items"
FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Lists/[ListName]/Design Items"
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the full server relative URL. If your site URL is https://contoso.com/sites/sitename/ then it should be like

```
FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/sites/sitename/Lists/[ListName]/Design Items"
```

you can also get the relative URL from ClientContext object like

```
 FolderServerRelativeUrl = ClientContext.Url+"/Lists/[ListName]/Design Items"
```